# Sorting, deleting from and appending to a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

I am trying to create a program that allows the user to choose whether to add something to, delete something from or sort a list. But for some reason it doesn't work - it just doesn't sort/delete/add.
Here is what I have:

```
countries = ["England", "Germany", "Spain", "Italy", "France", "Turkey", 
  "Greece", "Austria", "America", "Ireland"]
print(countries)
print(" ")

def menu ():
  countries = ["England", "Germany", "Spain", "Italy", "France", "Turkey", 
    "Greece", "Austria", "America", "Ireland"]

  print ("Select the option you require: \n \n 1. Add a new country \n 2. 
    delete a country \n 3. Sort the list \n ")

  option = input("Please enter 1, 2 or 3: ")

  if option == "1":
     addition = input("Enter the country you would like to add: ").title()
     countries = countries.append(addition)

  elif option == "2":
     removes = input("Enter the country you would like to delete").title()

     countries = countries.remove(removes)
  elif option == "3":
     countries.sort()

  else:
     print ("You can only enter 1, 2 or 3 \n")
     menu()

menu()
print(countries)
```

This is what the console produces when I select to sort the list:

```
 ['England', 'Germany', 'Spain', 'Italy', 'France', 'Turkey', 'Greece', 
 'Austria', 'America', 'Ireland']

Select the option you require: 

 1. Add a new country 
 2. Delete a country 
 3. Sort the list 

Please enter 1, 2 or 3:  3
['England', 'Germany', 'Spain', 'Italy', 'France', 'Turkey', 'Greece', 
 'Austria', 'America', 'Ireland']
```

When I was expecting the list to be sorted into ascending alphabetical order.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your countries inside `menu` is not the same variable as it is outside... So regardless of what you're doing - it's not doing anything to the countries you're printing after calling `menu()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you have to define all the countries twice tells you that something is wrong. You have *two different* variables both names `countries`, one in the module scope and one inside of the function. A cheap and easy solution is to make the module level variable available for mutation inside of the function using the `global` keyword:

```
countries = ["England", "Germany", "Spain", "Italy", "France", "Turkey", 
  "Greece", "Austria", "America", "Ireland"]
print(countries)
print(" ")

def menu ():
  # Get the countries variable from the module scope
  global countries

  print ("Select the option you require: \n \n 1. Add a new country \n 2. delete a country \n 3. Sort the list \n ")

  option = input("Please enter 1, 2 or 3: ")

  if option == "1":
     addition = input("Enter the country you would like to add: ").title()
     countries = countries.append(addition)

  elif option == "2":
     removes = input("Enter the country you would like to delete").title()

     countries = countries.remove(removes)
  elif option == "3":
     countries.sort()

  else:
     print ("You can only enter 1, 2 or 3 \n")
     menu()

menu()
print(countries)
```

Using global variables in this way is generally considered bad style. Consider instead to pass the list of countries as an argument to the `menu` function.

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting the countries list in your method menu, which has no effect to the list outside your method. You can print the list just after you sort it

```
  elif option == "3":
      countries.sort()
      print(countries)
```

or you delete the list in the method you can hand over the list to the method and return it.

I hope I could help you.